# ID Provider in SAML

Tags: java, saml

I have read about SAML2.0 and understood most of the concepts. Now I want to try it for my Web Application. I understand that Once the user visits my site, he has to be redirected to the Id Provider along with the SAML request and then the Id Provider sends back the SAML response. 
The problem here is the **Id Provider**. How to get an Id Provider(say Google). Please tell me how to proceed? 
Can I myself become an Id Provider from a different website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working with SAML, it is quite complex protocol.
First have a look here, and then if you have more questions just ask:
http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/fedlogininterp/saml-idp

> Can I myself become an Id Provider from a different website?

Yes you can

Comment: If I want to become an ID Provider, What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do, let's say that you establish IdP, you need to have means of authenticating people (by credentials or certificats etc.). Then once you receive SAML authentication request you do some proper authentication on the backend and send valid authentication response (statement)

Comment: That is what I want to know. For sending response, do I need to follow any method or I can provide my own set of statements in xml(saml) format?

Comment: You need to comply with SAML specs. Check this out: http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-authn-context-2.0-os.pdf. Again, it depends what do you want/need to have.

Comment: Thank you. That will help me I guess. One more thing I want to know.I authenticated an user successfully. If the same user wants to access some other service from same Service provider in the same session, then can I give him direct access to that service without asking for authentication details again. I know it can be done but can you tell me how to achieve this? Will cookie be helpful in anyway? just confused

Comment: Nope, you need to add 'authentication statement' to SAML message, so whenever you redirect user from one point (SP) to another, the backend first check if the SAML contains authentication statement, if it does it knows that the incoming user is already authenticated. Usually you put username/email/identifier as 'subject' in SAML message.

Comment: I want to give the authenticated user access to services for a limited time(lets say 5 minutes) on One authentication. How to keep track of time. I mean if the user asks for a service after five minutes from his first authenticated login, I should ask him for login details again.

Comment: @Stugal : suraj is right. How will you keep track of the time without the cookie?

Comment: SAML AuthStatement contains time at which user was authenticated 'IssueInstant="2012-03-22T08:46:12.739Z"', having that you can check if the session should or shouldn't be valid